# Is there a way to programatically get AWS Access Key and Secret Access Key in C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-4.0

I read the AWS credentials best practice and the [Access Key Management](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/access-key-management-for-net-applications-part-1/) article which both suggest to put the Access Key and Secret Access Key in App.config. Is there another way to do it, such as when the app is running in an instance, automatically grabs the credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the application is running in an instance - and I assume you mean EC2 instance - then the instance can be started with a IAM role that already has/knows the access keys - the application itself never needs to know or use the keys, the AWSSDK does it on your behalf - you app just makes AWS API calls and the instance 'magically' supplies the keys for you.

Using an IAM role for the instance would be the best practice.